# IFolderLayout addView Open folder source code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I added folders to `addView()` in the bottom area, through `IFolderLayout` as below source. Is there a way to open the folder as a source instead of clicking it with the mouse?

```
IFolderLayout left = layout.createFolder("left", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25F, layout.getEditorArea());
    left.addView(JavaUI.ID_PACKAGES);                                                   
    left.addView("org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator");                             

    // Bottom
    IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.75F, layout.getEditorArea());
    bottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROBLEM_VIEW);                                        // problems
    bottom.addView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);                                  // console
    bottom.addView("org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView");                            // servers
    bottom.addView("org.eclipse.search.ui.views.SearchView");                           // search
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jn1c.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'open the folder as a source'?

Comment: Click on the folder with the mouse to enter the view. To replace these events with sources.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what you mean by 'replace these events with sources'. [edit] your question and explain in more detail exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
Added image.
I'm asking how to view the bottom area as if it were clicked instead of clicking the bottom area like a red box in the image.

Comment: If you mean you don't want the view to show initially you use `addPlaceholder` instead of `addView` to just define where the view goes when it opens.